# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{i^n}{n}$ converge?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{i^n}{n}$$

I'm not sure how to approach this series to find if it converges/diverges because of the $i^n$. I tried using the comparison test comparing it with $\frac{1}{n}$ and the ratio test, but didn't get anywhere. How would you approach this and look at series of this form or how to look at $i^n$ in an infinite series?

Comment: Is $i$ here a square root of $-1$ or the index of summation?

Comment: Assuming you mean $\sum_{n=1}^\infty i^n/n$ (note that I've used $n$ as the index of summation so that $i$ is the imaginary unit), then just break it into it's real ($n$ even) and imaginary ($n$ odd) parts. The alternating series test should be applicable to both those parts.

Comment: If $i$ is actually supposed to be the index of summation, which seems weird, then this series is basically the Riemann Zeta Function divided by $n$.

Comment: Sorry, it is n = 1

Comment: And $i = \sqrt{-1}$, not some real number, correct?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{i^n}{n} = i\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{2m+1}- \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{2m+2}$ and both are alternated series

Comment: @Clarinetist Yes, i is the imaginary number

Comment: $i^{4k}=1;i^{4k+1}=ixi^{4k+2}=-1;i^{4k+3}=-i $.  So $\sum i^n/n= \sum 1/4n +i\sum 1/(4n+1)-\sum 1/(4n+2)-i\sum 1/(4n+3) = \sum [1/4n -1/(4n+2)] + i\sum [1/(4n+1)-1/(4n+3)]=\sum 1/2n (4n+2) + i\sum 2/(4n+1)(4n+3) $

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^n}n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^{2n}}{2n}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^{2n-1}}{2n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(i^2)^{n}}{2n}+ i\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(i^2)^{n-1}}{2n-1}$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n}+ i\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}$

Now, you have two alternating series. Use the [Alternating Series Test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/AlternatingSeries.aspx) to see if they converge.

A similar idea goes into how we derive the relation $e^{ix}=\cos x +i\sin x$.

Comment: For $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(i^2)^{n}}{2n}+ i\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(i^2)^{n-1}}{2n-1}$ isn't the top part of  $i\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(i^2)^{n-1}}{2n-1}$ supposed to be $(i^2)^{n-\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: I factored out an $i$ in an intermdiate step. It goes from $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$ to $i\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^{2n-2}}{2n-1}$ to $i\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^{2(n-1)}}{2n-1}$ to $i\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(i^2)^{n-1}}{2n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $i^n = i^{n+4}$,
each 4 consecutive terms
is of the form

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{i}{4m+1}+\frac{-1}{4m+2}+\frac{-i}{4m+3}+\frac{1}{4m+4}
&=\frac{i}{4m+1}+\frac{-1}{4m+2}+\frac{-i}{4m+3}+\frac{1}{4m+4}\\
&=i(\frac{1}{4m+1}-\frac{1}{4m+3})-\frac{1}{4m+2}+\frac{1}{4m+4}\\
&=i(\frac{(4m+3)-(4m+1)}{(4m+1)(4m+3)})-(\frac{(4m+4)-(4m+2)}{(4m+2)(4m+4)})\\
&=i(\frac{2}{(4m+1)(4m+3)})-(\frac{2}{(4m+2)(4m+4)})\\
\end{array}
$

Since each of the
real and imaginary parts
are less than
$\frac{2}{(4m+1)^2}$,
and the sum of these converges
absolutely,
the overall sum converges
conditionally.

To write this out explicitly,
this shows that

$\begin{array}\\
|\sum_{k=1}^{4n} \dfrac{i^k}{k}|
&=|\sum_{m=1}^n (i(\dfrac{2}{(4m+1)(4m+3)})-(\dfrac{2}{(4m+2)(4m+4)})|\\
&\le\sum_{m=1}^n |(\dfrac{2}{(4m+1)(4m+3)})|+\sum_{m=1}^n|(\dfrac{2}{(4m+2)(4m+4)})|\\
&\lt\sum_{m=1}^n |(\dfrac{2}{(4m+1)^2})|+\sum_{m=1}^n|(\dfrac{2}{(4m+2)^2})|\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^n 2(\dfrac{1}{(4m+1)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(4m+2)^2})\\
\end{array}
$

and this sum converges.

There are at most
3 additional terms in any sum
beyond the $4n$
and these contribute
at most
$\dfrac{3}{4n}$
which goes to zero,
so they do not affect 
the convergence.