# Proof that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{i^k}{k}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I checked this on Wolfram Alpha and it says that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{i^k}{k}$ converges. I can't seem to prove it though. I tried it using the direct comparison test and root test. The other ones don't really make sense (we've only proven direct comparison test, root test and Leipniz criteria as well as like harmonic series convergence and stuff. We have also proven that a complex series converges if the series of their imaginary part and their real part converges. The series of the real part would be $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{0}{k}=0$ right? So the series of the real part converges. For the imaginary part: $\displaystyle i\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}$ which diverges. Does that mean the series diverges generally? I'm confused by what wolfram alpha tells me.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/653766/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2004192/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2022181/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cdisplaystyle%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Cexact%7Bi%7D%5Ek%7D%7Bk%7D%24)

Comment: [math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546440](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546440/show-that-s-sum-n-1-infty-fracinn-is-convergent)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show that $ s = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{i^n}{n} $ is convergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546440/show-that-s-sum-n-1-infty-fracinn-is-convergent)

Comment: As there are multiple duplicates, does it make sense to close some of the duplicates as duplicates of other duplicates?

Comment: Why the donwvotes? It doesn't have sense. The OP is showing your attempts!